# USB devices in android, without a module in the android kernel

Tags: linux, qemu, android, chroot

I have a rather strange theoretical question.
For example, when I connect a USB device to my Linux AMD64 PC, the functionality of this USB device depends on the presence of the corresponding module in the Linux kernel. And if there is a module, then the device will work, but if there is no module, then compilation from the source remains.
But what if the PC is not amd64, but for example Android ARM64 for which it is problematic to compile the module.
Based on the above, I came up with this option.

---

Step one:

Set up the chroot "arch or debian", and forward the USB device to it.

Step two:

Install a virtual machine "Qemu" as chroot and forward USB to it

Step three:

Install Linux on the Virtual Machine with a full-fledged Kernel and the ability to install modules.

---

I mean, for example, when you connect an unusual USB device to MacOS and you don’t have modules for it, but this device works under Windows, in this case it remains to install Windows on a virtual machine under MacOS and forward the USB to Windows

Thus, theoretically, you can connect any USB device to android. So far, I have not tested this method, an interesting opinion. Is it possible?

Comment: What problems have you run into compiling modules for Android on Aarch64?

Comment: @StephenKitt I don"t have kernel source

Comment: a driver can be built in rather than module. check the kernel config

Comment: no, theoretically you will be able to connect any USB device supported by the linux kernel with your VM... it's not as if you will magically use an unsupported device with android, just because your VM recognizes it...

Comment: on your android device kernel modules are signature enforced therefore one must build whole kernel anyway - not possible without kernel source code

Comment: @jrdnjhntsn I get it, but that's the whole point. i need to use android and virtual machine as bridge between physical usb device and linux system

Comment: @alecxs Even having the source code is a big problem because I can't compile for ARM. that is why I am looking for a workaround, such as the one described above, through QEMU

Comment: you can compile for ARM. that's what the cross-compile ndk toolchains are made for. but you don't have source code